# Is there some way to update a list in real-time that is fed from data from a NV memory that is being updated on the fly in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state, recoiljs

As it stands right now, I have an App that tracks the user location, and saves user location coordinates, and the timestamp, whenever the user stops somewhere, when this happens the this data (coordinates and timestamp) is stored in the smartphone's NV memory, till that part everything is ok. The thing is, when another stop, if you will, is saved into the memory, the stops' list doesn't update (that expected), but I need to update this list (or even re-render the screen with the list) when a stop is saved into the memory, how can I do that?

I'm a complete noobie in mobile development, and JS, let alone in react-native, thus I'm not aware of the best way to do some (most actually) things in react native, and maybe the things I tried (bellow) are not way to solve the problem that I'm facing right now.

Some things I tried:

- Recoil state management: I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lO56p58cJ8Y&ab_channel=TheFlutterFactory) tutorial alongside its [repo](https://github.com/theflutterfactory/React-Native-Tutorials/blob/recoil_tutorial/src/hooks/useFoodList.js), but it keep throwing the error by the lines of: "hooks must be used inside function components" even though the hooks were inside a function, just like in the tutorial.
- Hookstate: it gave even 'worse' error messages.

How I used Recoil:
The class below detects when the user is a new location and will call LocationChange() when it happens:

```
export default class Geolocation {

  constructor(){
    // Nothing
  }

  // Properties/Variables:
  static userStopped = true;
  static userOnFoot = true;

  static async config(){
    
    BackgroundGeolocation.onLocation(location => {
      LocationChange(location);
    }, error => {
      console.log("[location] ERROR: ", error);
    });
[...]
```

This is what the function that save the data into the NV memory and (should) updates the state looks like:

> Obs: I've put this function outside class because as far as I'm aware classes and hooks don't get along very well and also, some use variables and if() doesn't make sense, but that's cause it is in debug phase, I need to 'force' data to be stored.

```
export const LocationChange = async (newLocation) => {
  const [newStops, setNewStops] = useRecoilState(stopsList);

  console.log('New location: ', newLocation);
  var newLatitude = newLocation.coords.latitude;
  var newLongitude = newLocation.coords.longitude;
  const isoStr = newLocation.timestamp;

  // Convert the ISO-8601 ts format into 'normal' ts
  const date = new Date(isoStr);
  const timestamp = date.getTime();

  const onFoot = true;
  const stopped = true;
  const closestClient = await GetClosestClient(newLatitude, newLongitude);

  var name = closestClient === 'nenhum'? 'Desconhecido': closestClient.name;

  const sameStop = await StopsDB.isSameStop(newLatitude, newLongitude);
  await StopsDB.saveAsLastStop(timestamp, closestClient.name, newLatitude, newLongitude);

  console.log('onFoot: ', onFoot, ' stopped: ', stopped, ' sameStop: ', sameStop);
  if(onFoot && stopped && sameStop){
    console.log('Saving this location! ----------------------',
      '\nName:........', name,
      '\nLatitude:....', newLatitude,
      '\nLongitude:...', newLongitude,
      '\nTime Stamp:..', timestamp);
    await StopsDB.registerStop(timestamp, name, newLatitude, newLongitude);
    var buf = await StopsDB.getAll();
    setNewStops(buf);
  } else {
    console.log('Do NOT save this new location!');
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hooks have to be inside function *components*, not just functions, are you sure you are putting them into components?

Comment: I put a code snippet into the question, is LocationChanged() understood as a function component by RN the way it is?